# How to start live555HLSProxy

Tags: http-live-streaming, rtsp, live555

I want to use `live555HLSProxy` to convert an RTSP stream.

First I've started live555MediaServer executable informing the stream is available at `rtsp://192.168.1.2:8554` address. When I play it with

```
ffplay rtsp://192.168.1.2:8554/test.mpeg
```

it works as expected. Now I want to convert that stream to HLS to view on web.

So, I've navigated to `/var/www/html` and started `live555HLSProxy` as described in [documenation page](http://www.live555.com/hlsProxy/)

```
/path/to/live555HLSProxy "rtsp://192.168.1.136:8554/test.mpg" test_stream
```

and it gives me such output

```
Created new TCP socket 3 for connection
[URL:"rtsp://192.168.1.136:8554/test.mpg/"]: This stream has no usable subsessions
```

Answer (score 1):

You did it in the correct way, but you should use a supported format, or implement it.

LIVE555 HLS Proxy support only H264/H265 video codec, as it is write in the [documentation](http://www.live555.com/hlsProxy/) :

> Note that the RTSP stream must contain H.264 or H.265 video,
> optionally with an AAC audio track. For now, no other codecs are
> supported.